# Python questions on ColumnTransformer and SimpleImputer/OnehotEncoding

Tags: python, one-hot-encoding

I have been experimenting with python and columnTransformer and I have a question.

This is the code that works. It does what I want, fills the empty cells with most frequent and uses onehotencoding, so the columns (only binary features I have) get doubled after OneHotEncoding, as it should. Every cell value is in string.

```
cate_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('imputer3',SimpleImputer(missing_values='', strategy='most_frequent')),
    ('onehot3',OneHotEncoder(sparse=False))
    ])

ColumnTransformer(transformers=[
    ('num', cate_transformer, binary_cols)
    ])

X = prepro.fit_transform(X)
```

This also works, it gives me the exact same result, it's without the ColumnTransformer:

```
BinImputer = SimpleImputer(missing_values='', strategy='most_frequent')
X = BinImputer.fit_transform(X)
Hot = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False)
X = Hot.fit_transform(X)
```

Now, to my questions...
This does not work:

```
column_trans = ColumnTransformer(
remainder='passthrough',
transformers=[
     ('SimpleImputer', SimpleImputer(missing_values='', strategy='most_frequent'), binary_cols)
])

column_trans1 = ColumnTransformer(
remainder='passthrough',
transformers=[
     ('OneHotEncoder', OneHotEncoder(sparse=False), binary_cols)
])` 

 X = column_trans.fit_transform(X)
 X = column_trans1.fit_transform(X)
```

It says: `ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)`

Also, this does not work: When I pass a dataframe with x rows and 2 columns, it returns x rows and 8 columns. Look:

```
column_trans1 = ColumnTransformer(
remainder='passthrough',
transformers=[
     ('SimpleImputer', SimpleImputer(missing_values='', strategy='most_frequent'), binary_cols),
     ('OneHotEncoder', OneHotEncoder(sparse=False), binary_cols)
])

X = column_trans1.fit_transform(X)
```

Before:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7MfE5.png)

After:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yh4zy.png)

1)It seems very strange to me. Why at the last code, the total number of columns is x4 and not x2, as it should in Onehotencoding. Also:
2)Why at the last code, the code runs (even if it gives me these 8 columns, instead of 4), whereas at the previous, where I do the same thing but in 2 steps (or I feel I do the same thing), it does not run at all?

So, I must be missing something important on the way they are implemented. I tried looking at the documentations, but I could not get it. Thank you in advance.